# Is there a way to make an error counter that terminates the program after a specific number of user inputs?

Tags: c, counter

I am a programming beginner. I made a program that converts integer inputs into roman numerals. It's a nonterminating program, and it can only terminate if the user inputs 5 errors.

```
int main(){
int i;
for(i = 1; i > 0; i++)
{
    int num;
    printf("\n\nEnter a positive integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    while(num == 0 || num < 0 || num > 3999 || i == 5)
    {
        if(i == 5)
        {
            int ch;
            printf("\n\nYou have reached 5 retries. Do you wish to continue?\n");
            printf("Press 1 to continue.\n");
            printf("Press 2 to terminate the program.\n");
            scanf("%d", &ch);

            if(ch == 1)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if(ch == 2)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Invalid input. The program will now terminate.");
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else if(num == 0)
        {
           printf("Error: Zero is Nulla");
            break;
        }
        else if(num < 0)
        {
            printf("Error: Input cannot be negative");
            break;
        }
        else if(num > 3999)
        {
            printf("Error: Input cannot be greater than 3999");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error: Input should be a positive integer");
            break;
        }
    }

    while(num > 0 && num <4000)
    {

        if (num >= 1000)       // 1000 - m
        {
           printf("m");
           num -= 1000;
        }
        else if (num >= 900)   // 900 -  cm
        {
           printf("cm");
           num -= 900;
        }
        else if (num >= 500)   // 500 - d
        {
           printf("d");
           num -= 500;
        }
        else if (num >= 400)   // 400 -  cd
        {
           printf("cd");
           num -= 400;
        }
        else if (num >= 100)   // 100 - c
        {
           printf("c");
           num -= 100;
        }
        else if (num >= 90)    // 90 - xc
        {
           printf("xc");
           num -= 90;
        }
        else if (num >= 50)    // 50 - l
        {
           printf("l");
           num -= 50;
        }
        else if (num >= 40)    // 40 - xl
        {
           printf("xl");
           num -= 40;
        }
        else if (num >= 10)    // 10 - x
        {
           printf("x");
           num -= 10;
        }
        else if (num >= 9)     // 9 - ix
        {
           printf("ix");
           num -= 9;
        }
        else if (num >= 5)     // 5 - v
        {
           printf("v");
           num -= 5;
        }
        else if (num >= 4)     // 4 - iv
        {
           printf("iv");
           num -= 4;
        }
        else if (num >= 1)     // 1 - i
        {
           printf("i");
           num -= 1;
        }

    }

}

return 0;}
```

It stops after 5 user inputs, but I don't want that. I want it to stop after specifically 5 errors. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is incremented in every iteration of the loop, that is why it stops after 5 iterations (5 user inputs). So:

1. Instead of the `for` loop, you should have a `while(1)` loop.
2. Instead of `int i;`, make an `int error_counter = 0;` before the main loop.
3. Then instead of `if(i == 5)`, you can write `++error_counter; if (error_counter == 5) { ... }`.
4. Also, the two inner "while" loop are actually just "if" conditions. So instead of `while(num == 0 || num < 0 || num > 3999 || i == 5)` and `while(num > 0 && num <4000)`, you should just use `if (num <= 0 || num > 3999) {...} else {...}`

Comment: Or even better than `while(1)` and `break`, you could just check if `error_counter` reaches 5 in the `while` condition.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 in general yes, but here he wants that when 5 errors are encountered, he asks the user whether to continue or not, so he need to stay inside the loop. So either it is done as it is now, or it can be done as you suggest, but the whole loop should be moved to its own function, that will be called again and again in another loop (that will end only when 5 errors occur + the user pressed "2" to terminate).

Comment: or, the condition in the loop can be: `while (ch != 2)`. This seems the best way.